# Do not want Html after php is executed

Tags: php, html

I have the following code:

```
<?php
... 
?>

<script>
....
</script>

<html>
 ...
</html>
```

After displaying HTML form, JavaScript should validate and then PHP should save in database and give a confirmation message.. but what happens is, after PHP is executed and success message is echoed, the HTML form also displays as it is below message..
What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Only show the html when it's needed.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're posting a form page back to the page it exists on. If so, just wrap your HTML in a PHP condition to check for the existence of a POST (or GET) variable.

Comment: Use an if clause to display the HTML form only if no form data was sent to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to set a variable if a form submission was successful. Something like the following:

```
<?php
$success = false;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // process form submission
    // if submission validates; set $success to true
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    …
  </head>
  <body>
<?php if ($success): ?>
    <p>Thank you for your submission!</p>
<?php else: ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
      …
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could end the script after progressing the data with `exit();` ([See docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php))

Like @Shomz said, you could wrap your HTML output in a if-statement to prevent it from being printed after processing your form data.

Comment: Yep, use exit(), everyone loves half-rendered pages

Comment: @DamienPirsy http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/ exit (or more appropriate, the concept behind it) has been around far longer than php is perfectly valid to use. Of course, you can abuse nearly every function, but exit() itself doesn't have ANYTHING to do with half-rendered pages as you call them.

Answer (score 0):

- put PHP in a different file (you can include HTML files)
- `return;`
- `die();`
- `exit();`
- Use `ob_start()` and functions alike to buffer HTML and `_clean` to flush it to nirvana when you don't need it.
- Submit to a different file (nearly the same as first point).
- Use prepend in **php.ini** to start ob before script, and append in php.ini to kill output under certain circumstances (maybe using `isset()` on a variable to check if there has been a submit or just `$_POST` / `$_GET` ).

You might also want to look at PRG pattern which someone else has already asked about for php here: [Simple Post-Redirect-Get code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142809/simple-post-redirect-get-code-example)

Comment: "If you need more options, there's probably tons of them." 
In what way does that help.

Comment: edited and changed, though I don't really get why you downvoted an answer which provides multiple solutions as well as stating that there are more (I could go out and list them all, but it won't help the OP)

Comment: i don't want in another file. also i tried die() n exit() at end of php. but den nothing loads, not even html.

Comment: Well your question was about how to not output the html ; if you only want to not output the form: <?php if (!isset($_POST['submit'])): ?><form ...>...<input type="submit" name="submit" value="send it!"></form><?php endif; ?>

Comment: That's because both die() and exit() end the execution of the script, and therefore any subsequent parsing/elaboration. Don't know why people keep suggesting here to use those

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){

//your insert query 
//your thanks message

}
else{
// Your html form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use  a flag variable :-

```
if(isset($some_var))
{

// do something 

}
else{
//  show html form
}
```

Comment: You should add how to set the "flag variable" by something he submits ($_GET/$_POST in most cases)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'action' of your form to send the post to another file where there is the confirmation message.

Or you cant put a condition `if(!$_POST)` before your html

Comment: If I had enought reputation I would mark Moeed Farooqui's answear as the right one;