# How can I prevent data insertion after page refresh?

Tags: php

i have one page having the php codes and the form. after an insertion if i refresh the page insertion is made again i would like to prevent that.

```
 if (!empty ($_POST['submit']) AND $_POST['submit'] == 'Save')
 {

 $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['nom']);
 $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$password=$_POST['password'];
 $sql = "INSERT INTO utilisateur VALUES ('', '$name', '$username', '$password')";
 $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  echo '<p style="text-align:center">Un utilisateur a ete ajoute avec succes !</p>';
}
else
 {

 }


  <form action="" method="post"  name="form"> 
  <label>Nom <em>*</em></label>
 <input type="text" name="nom" onkeyup="verif_name(this);" required />
  <label>Nom utilisateur <em>*</em></label>
 <input type="text" name="username" required /></br></br>
  <label >Password <em>*</em></label>
 <input type="password"   name= "password" id= "password">

  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
 </form>
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: ^ This. Redirect the user to the same page. If you want to show a "success" message you have to save stuff to the users session. An easy pre-built solution would be to [use session flashes](https://github.com/plasticbrain/PhpFlashMessages).

Comment: would it be a matter if you show me how to use session flashes in my exemple ?

Answer (score 0):

Use redirection and different files and URIs

form.php:

```
<?php 
    if (!empty($_COOKIE['message']))
    {
        $message = $_COOKIE['message'];
        setcookie('message', '');
        echo '<p>' . $message . '</p>';
    }
?>
<form action="action.php" method="post" name="form">
    <label>Nom <em>*</em></label>
    <input type="text" name="nom" onkeyup="verif_name(this);" required />
    <label>Nom utilisateur <em>*</em></label>
    <input type="text" name="username" required />
    <br /><br />
    <label>Password <em>*</em></label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

action.php:

```
<?php
    if (!empty ($_POST['submit']) AND $_POST['submit'] == 'Save')
    {
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['nom']);
        $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO utilisateur VALUES ('', '$name', '$username', '$password')";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        setcookie('message', 'Un utilisateur a ete ajoute avec succes !');
    } else {
        setcookie('message', 'Error!');
    }
        header('Location: /form.php');
?>
```

Comment: Even better, try and use AJAX

Comment: Thank you for codes the insertion problem is solved but the message in the cookie keeps displaying on the top of the form even after i leave the page or log out

Comment: i did it as well behold the answer i got from php : Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\www\upage\administrateur.php:9) in C:\wamp\www\upage\administrateur.php on line 120.   // Line 120 is  setcookie('message', '');

Comment: Sorry, you cannot set a cookie after you echo something :)

Comment: i change it problem still there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102614/discussion-between-branche-and-mihai-rducanu).

Answer (score -1):

There is actually a design pattern that adresses this issue and it is called "POST/REDIRECT/GET"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

The concept is very simple, after posting some info to the server, you return a redirect header to some page so that the user is does not resubmit the infos twice on F5

A crude example is presented in this question:

[Simple Post-Redirect-Get code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142809/simple-post-redirect-get-code-example)

Comment: Why the down vote ? My answer provides examples and explanations and is based on a so called "good practice" and "design patterns"

Comment: Probably because you just took the same link I posted 40 minutes before you and didn't add anything than a link to an existing question. Your answer should be complete, not a link to wikipedia and another SO question.

Comment: i'm the one who posts the question it's not me who down vote you