# Clicking the browser back button after getting the confirmation page

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, jinja2

I have a page where I have to fill the student details for example name, email and department. Once I fill the details and click the `submit my button` it goes to next page and it shows the entered student details in the next page.

Here I have shown the code step by step.

The below code after entering the details and clicking the submit button.

```
<div class="top-space-20">
    <input class="btn btn-info" type="button" onclick="submitEvent()" class="btn" value="submit my details">
</div>
```

This is the script code for clicking the submit my details button.

```
function submitEvent() {
    form = document.createElement("form");
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "/confirmation";
}
```

Once I clicked the button it goes to backend and fetch some details and it displays the `confirmation.html` page.

```
@app.route("/confirm",methods=['GET','POST'])
def confirm():
    "Confirming the event message"
    response_value = request.args['value']

    return render_template("confirmation.html", value=json.loads(response_value))

@app.route("/confirmation", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ssubmit_and_confirm():
    "submit an event and display confirmation"

    if request.method == 'POST':       
        return redirect(url_for('confirm', value=value))
```

The below code is the confirmation.html page

```
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="max-width:1000px;max-height: 800px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
        <div class="panel-heading " style="text-align: center;">submit student details</div>
        <div class="panel-body" id="resultDiv">
            <div class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <label class="col-md-8" for="Date:">Date:
                            {{ value }}</br> Time :{{value}}</label>
                        <label class="col-md-8" for="dateApplied"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <label class="col-md-8" for="student email:">
                            student email id:{{value}}</label>
                    </div>
                </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

So the problem here is once I come to the `confirmation.html` and if I click the browser back button it goes to the form and it lets me add the same details.

To avoid this I tried including this lines in the `confirmation.html`

```
</div>
<div><input type="hidden" id="reloadPage" /></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function reloadPage(){
            location.reload(true); ;    // RELOAD PAGE ON BUTTON CLICK EVENT.

            // SET AUTOMATIC PAGE RELOAD TIME TO 5000 MILISECONDS (5 SECONDS).
            var timerId = setInterval('refreshPage()', 5000);
        }
    });
    function refreshPage() { clearInterval(timerId); location.reload(); }
</script>
```

But it's not working. I tried one more method which is given in the link
[How to stop re submitting a form after clicking back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511043/how-to-stop-re-submitting-a-form-after-clicking-back-button)

This is also not working.

So what do I need is if I click the back button in the browser I should display the confirmation page only or it should tell this is not the authourized page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:
On the form submission page, initially set the form submission value to false.

`sessionStorage.setItem('form-submit', false)`

Step 2:
And when submitting the form in previous page, check:

```
function submitEvent() {
    formSubmitted = sessionStorage.getItem('form-submit')

    if (!formSubmitted){
        // Write your code here
    }
}
```

Step 3:
On `confirmation.html` page, you can store a submission value in sessionStorage.

`sessionStorage.setItem('form-submit', true)`

Answer (score 0):

You could add HTML5 history api. Use following code .

```
name = document.title
history.pushState(null,name,name)//add this code in your configuration.html file in document ready block
$(window).on("popstate",()=>{
   //....Do whatever you want
   /*If you want to display unauthorized page then
   $(document).html("Unauthorized page")
   */
})
```

Answer (score 0):

store the form data and reset the form just before the form data is sent to the server. Assuming that you are using $.ajax() to submit the form.

```
function submitEvent() {
    form = document.createElement("form");
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "/confirmation";

    // Add id attribute to the form
    form.id = "student_details_form";

    // Collect form data

    // reset your form just before calling $.ajax() or $.post()
    document.getElementById('student_details_form').reset();

    // call $.ajax() or $.post()
    $.ajax({
        url: form.action,
        // snipps
    };

}
```