# F5/refresh button and forward button issue after using POST method in a form

Tags: php

I read the answer here [Simple Post-Redirect-Get code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142809/simple-post-redirect-get-code-example/4142969#4142969), in my code, this works **only** when I clicked/pressed the back button. This is the process of the code

1. POST
2. Validates and if passed insert the data to database
3. Redirect them to the same page `Redirect::in($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) //I applied the accepted answer on the link here.`

Problems are:

- F5/refresh = `confirm submit form` is appearing.
- Forward button = Document expired.

How can I solve this problem? I am aware/search of **PRG pattern** but failed to fully understand it and tried the accepted answer on the link but I still have some problem.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I am not using any.

Comment: This code: `Redirect::in(...)` is not pure PHP - it's clearly part of some library.  Try using simple `header("Location: {$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");`