# Post/Redirect/Get works on XAMPP, returns blank page on production server

Tags: php, session, post

Being near the finish line of a project I've been working on for the last couple of weeks, I recently uploaded it for the 1st time to my server to check for any issues. Although almost everything worked flawlessly, there is one issue I can't wrap my head around!

**Description:**

It's an online store that stores the user's cart in the `$_SESSION['id']` variable. Everything is handled with POST requests. Upon clicking the `<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add to cart" id="addToCart">` Button, the form checks if the product ID is already present in `$_SESSION['id']`. If that is the case, `break` is called to prevent adding the product multiple times. As the form's action directs back to the same file, it should in theory just refresh. To circumvent then annoying notification a user gets upon refreshing the page/using the back button after the POST request (and to prevent the form to be sent multiple times), I resulted to a Post/Redirect/Get code snippet from this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142809/simple-post-redirect-get-code-example) post. As (I believe) my shared hosting at one.com runs Apache, I used the rewrite approach.

**Situation on XAMPP:**

Visitor navigates to /sub/0.php (the site of the 1st product), selects his clothes size and hits Add to cart. After that, the product ID gets appended to $_SESSION['id'], the page refreshes with `?status=success` at the end and a small shopping cart appears on the top right corner.

**Situation on the production server (error messages turned on):**

Visitor navigates to /sub/0.php (the site of the 1st product), selects his clothes size and hits Add to cart. The product ID gets appended correctly (I can check on cart.php and it shows up), though upon refresh there is EITHER

1. a blank page
2. a blank page showing just a "0" (this seems to be the ID of the 1st product I add to the cart, I once added the product with ID 3 first and it then displayed a 3)
3. the warning "Already in cart". This is the weird part! The warning is in the code within the if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) statement, so it should only be visible after the button was pressed. "Already in cart" even shows when the page is reloaded. I have to manually click in the URL bar and hit Enter to get the view. In this [video](https://youtu.be/H742fwLMa3E), you can see in detail what I mean.

What's wrong with my code, why does it work on XAMPP but doesn not work on the production server? The PGR doesn't seem to work at all (or the code never gets as far as to even execute the PGR due to the break being called), it also doesn't append the status=success behind the URL.

I'm really at a loss here, every input would be greatly appreciated!

Here's all the code for a product's site:

```
<?php
session_start();
$id=0;
include (__DIR__."/../includes/php/database.php");

if (isset($_POST['Sumbit'])) {
    // echo "submitted";
    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

        if (gettype($_SESSION['id'])=="string") {       //if there are already multiple IDs stored withinSESSION['id'] --> String
            for ($i=0; $i < strlen($_SESSION['id']); $i++) { 
                if ($id == $_SESSION['id'][$i]) {      //if there are multiple IDs already in cart and one of them matches with $id (--> multiple items are in the cart, but the current one is not)
                    echo "<script>alert('Already in Cart!')</script>";        //before implementing PRG, this alert appeared always when trying to add the product twice. Since I implemented PRG, it wasn't triggered once in XAMPP
                    $alreadyInCart=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isset($alreadyInCart)) {               //if already some IDs stored within$_SESSION['id'], but$id is not(--> more than 1 other products are in the cart, but the current one is not)
                $_SESSION['id'].=$id;
                $_SESSION['size'].=$_POST['Size'];
            }
        }else{                                          //if$_STRING['id'] isn't a 'string' (it's an 'integer' --> just one item in the cart), there's no need (nor possibility) to loop.
            echo $_SESSION['id'];                       
            if($id==$_SESSION['id']){                   //Just one item in cart, but that matches with$id (--> current item already in cart)
                $alreadyInCart=true;
                echo "<script>alert('Nur 1 Artikel im Warebkorb-Already in Cart!')</script>"; //before implementing PRG, this alert appeared always when trying to add the product twice. Since I implemented PRG, it wasn't triggered once in XAMPP
            }else{                                      //Just 1 item in cart but $id doesn't match with $_SESSION['id'](--> current item not yet in cart)
                $_SESSION['id'].=$id;
                $_SESSION['size'].=$_POST['Size'];
            }
        }
    }else{                                              //If $_SESSION['id'] doesn't even exist yet --> = instead of .=
        $_SESSION['id']=$id;
        $_SESSION['size']=$_POST['Size'];
    }
    // Post redirect get https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get
    $get_info = "?status=success";
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$get_info);
    echo $_GET['status'];
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <title>CNTRST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../includes/css/styles1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../includes/fonts/fonts.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/main.js"></script>

    <link id="essential" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../includes/css/sub_styles.css">
    <?php 
        if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
            if (isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status']=="success") {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/cart.js"></script>';
            }
        }
     ?>

</head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <?php 
                if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                        include(__DIR__)."/../includes/php/cart_icon.php";
                }
             ?>
            <img id="logo" src="../includes/media/img/icons/logo.svg"></img>
            <div class="slideshow">
                <img src="../includes/media/img/slideshow/bg.png" id="slideshow_bg">
                <img class="slideshow_objects" src="../<?php echo $product->product_image; ?>">
            </div>

            <div class="description">
                <h1><?php echo $product->product_name; ?></h1>
                <h2></h2>
                <ul>
                    <?php echo $product->product_desc; ?>
                </ul>
                <strong id="price"><?php echo $product->product_price; ?> <span class="currency">€</span></strong>
                <form action="<?php echo $id ?>.php" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label for="Size">Size</label>
                        <select name="Size" id="Size">
                            <option value="0">XS </option>
                            <option value="1">S </option>
                            <option value="2">M </option>
                            <option value="3">L </option>
                            <option value="4">XL </option>
                            <option value="5">XXL </option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="hidden" name="Product_Name" value="Marble print"><br>
                        <input type="submit" name="Sumbit" value="Add to cart" id="addToCart">
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
            <?php include "../includes/php/footer.php" ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

Upon adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of the code, I didn't receive a blank page, but an error message stating:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/6/5/2/cntrst.at/httpd.www/includes/php/database.php:1) in /customers/6/5/2/cntrst.at/httpd.www/sub/0.php on line 40 Notice: Undefined index: status in /customers/6/5/2/cntrst.at/httpd.www/sub/0.php on line 41

database.php contains:

```
   <?php
     ini_set('session.cache_limiter','public');
    session_cache_limiter(false);
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db   = 'DB_NAME';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $con = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    if (isset($cart)) {

    }else{
        $product = $con->query("
                    SELECT * FROM products
                    WHERE id=$id
        ");
        $product = $product->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Whats your error logs say? `https://www.one.com/static/support-guide-logfiles.do?locale=en`

Comment: I contacted Support because the tutorial wasn't working. They told me that logdata is not offered anymore, but he can hook me up with a one-time log data readout for a desired day. Is there a way for me to implement logging myself? I logged simple things like IP-Address and time before, but that surely won't be enough to gather more insight.

Comment: Try enabling error reporting within your script, add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1')` at the top of your php file.

Comment: I tried that yesterday, but somehow it didn't output anything. Weirdly enough, today it indeed threw an error as seen in my edit above!

Comment: I can't tell from your edit, but the errors are quite clear.. you have output before setting your header (could be a single char like a space or a BOM).. which is causing the `header("Location: "` header to fail, its then hitting the exit, and as `$_GET['status']` is not set it outputs nothing. Why are you doing anything other than connecting to the database within your database.php file? Also `$id` is not set so again that will fail.. plus you're not using prepared queries.. time to hit some more tutorials.

Comment: I got it to work: The error in the database file was indeed a space before the <?php, the rest were the 2 echo "<script>Already in cart</script>"; What do you mean the $id is not set? It's set to 0 which happens to be the product id. Also, the rest in the database file is simply because that's all I need from the database as a whole, so why add the if statement at the end to every single file when it's enough to add it once? :)