# refresh = on submit in php, how to fix it?

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am creating an insert process in php but I have a problem in my code. when I `refresh` my page, it will also `submit` and `insert` the data.

here is my code :

```
<form action="/drupal/node/1" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
Price: <input type="text" name="price" />
Minutes: <input type="text" name="minutes" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

// some code
mysql_select_db("zain", $con);
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['minutes']))
{
 $val_name = $_POST['name'];
 $val_price = $_POST['price'];
 $val_min = $_POST['minutes'];
 $max_id_sql = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM card_category");
 $data = mysql_fetch_array($max_id_sql);
 if ($data[0]==0)
 {
    $val_id = 1;
 }
 else
 {
    $val_id = $data[0] + 1;
 }

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO card_category (id, name, price, minutes) VALUES ($val_id,'$val_name',$val_price,$val_min )");
 $_POST['name'] == NULL;
 $_POST['price'] == NULL;
 $_POST['minutes'] == NULL;
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM card_category");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>price</th>
<th>mins</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['minutes'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
if (isset($_POST['lastname']))
{
print $_POST['lastname'];
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

my question is, how can I handle when I `refresh` the page and it will not `submit` the data?

thanks in advance

Comment: Check the very first answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827242/understanding-post-redirect-get

Comment: @gadss — You have [a major security hole](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you get the POST submission:

1. Process the data
2. Return a Redirect response
3. Get a GET request from the browser on the URL you redirect to
4. Respond to that with the HTML

If the browser is refreshed, it will resubmit the GET request which your PHP won't use to modify the database.

This is the [POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). There are some more details [in this blog entry](http://www.andypemberton.com/engineering/the-post-redirect-get-pattern/) (which also has example PHP code in the comments).

Comment: practically Quentin means to use header('Location: *url*'); Read his link it's a concept you should be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

How to fix refresh the page do not post the value using php:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']=="")
{
// process the data
}
```

Comment: Could you add some comments for your code? Why you think this is the solution, explain yourself a bit more.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at **$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']** variable, it will say **'POST'** when the user submitted data and **'GET'** when he did not. So:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
   // process the data
}
```

By the way, your code is eminently vulnerable to SQLI attacks ...

Comment: When the browser is refreshed, it will make the same request as it made to get the page in the first place … which is a post request, so that won't work.