# Why does script not skip over MySQL data insertion?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Newbie here learning PHP/MySQL.

When I fill in the form fields with data, it works fine and inserts data into the database.

When I leave the form blank, and click "`ADD RECORD`" button, I expect $temp to evaluate to null, but it does not `(echos as =1)`, and `"$_POST['firstname'])"` echos as blank - I would think this should cause `$temp` to evaluate to null and skip the `"if..."` database insertion.  But, an empty record is created `(text fields blank, userlevel=1)`. Why does `$temp` not equate to "`null`"?

Also, each time I reload the script using the browser's refresh button, the program seems to remember the last entries in the form and creates another record of the same.  I would have thought the `"$_POST = array();"` would have cleared all of this data, returned a null, and not create any new entry.  Would help if I got some clarification here.  Thanks, in advance.

Code is below:

```
<?php
//member table query - dbmemberquery.php
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

//form for data entry       
echo <<<_END
<form action="dbmemberquery.php" method="post"><pre>
    Firstname   <input type="text" name="firstname" />
    Lastname    <input type="text" name="lastname" />
    Email       <input type="text" name="email" />
    Password    <input type="text" name="password" />
    Userlevel   <input type="text" name="userlevel" />  
                <input type="submit" value="ADD RECORD" />  
</pre></form>
_END;

//inserting records into member table
function get_post($var)
    {
        return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
    }   

//check if all fields are filled in on the form
$temp = (isset($_POST['firstname']) &&
    isset($_POST['lastname']) &&
    isset($_POST['email']) &&
    isset($_POST['password']) &&
    isset($_POST['userlevel']));

//debug only - check values
echo "_post value for firstname = ".$_POST['firstname']."<br />";
echo "isset _post value =" .(isset($_POST['firstname']))."<br />";
echo "temp variable =".$temp."<br />"; 

if ($temp)
    {

        $firstname  = get_post('firstname');
        $lastname   = get_post('lastname');
        $email      = get_post('email');
        $password   = get_post('password');
        $userlevel  = get_post('userlevel');


        $query2 = "INSERT INTO sc2.members(firstname, lastname, email,password,userlevel)".
        "VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$password','$userlevel')";

        if (!mysql_query($query2, $db_server))
            echo "INSERT failed: $query2<br />" . 
            mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";

        $_POST = array();

    }

$_POST = array();


$query = "SELECT * FROM sc2.members";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: ". mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
//shows number of rows in member table
echo "rows: ".$rows . '<br />'.'<br />';

//lists all of the members
for ($j = 0; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo 'ID: '         . $row[0] . '<br />';
    echo 'firstname: '  . $row[1] . '<br />';
    echo 'lastname: '   . $row[2] . '<br />';
    echo 'email: '      . $row[3] . '<br />';
    echo 'password: '   . $row[4] . '<br />';
    echo 'userlevel: '  . $row[5] . '<br />';
    echo '<br />';
}

mysql_close($db_server);
```

Comment: try empty() to check null vaules

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 0):

> When I leave the form blank, and click "ADD RECORD" button, I expect $temp to evaluate to null,

No, the fields are in the form so they are *set*, they are just set to empty strings.

Use [`empty`](http://php.net/empty/) (and maybe combine it with something even more specific such a regular expression) instead of `is_set`.

> I would have thought the "$_POST = array();" would have cleared all of this data, returned a null, and not create any new entry.

No. That clears the data in the PHP variable.

When you refresh the browser it is the *browser* that remembers the contents of the form and  resubmits it, the PHP program runs *from the start* again, and PHP populates `$_POST` with a fresh copy of the data.

Use the [post-redirect-get pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827242/understanding-post-redirect-get) to avoid the data being resubmitted.