# How to redirect REST service from Get to Post?

Tags: rest, redirect, jax-rs, resteasy, response.redirect

How do I redirect a GET REST service to a POST REST service.
I am using resteasy and I tried

1. Response.seeOther
2. Response.temporaryRedirect

From what I see, both these methods could make GET requests only.

Is there a way to make POST calls using the above APIs?
Redirect is important to me because I want the browser to be aware of the new URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Don't do it.

`GET` and `POST` have well defined semantics. A `GET` is intended for reading resources whereas a `POST` is usually used to create or update a resource. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947).

It does not make sense to redirect from a `GET` to a `POST` because a user should be sure that he doesn't change the state of a resource if he uses a `GET`.

For the other way round there's a common pattern called [POST-Redirect-GET (PRG)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14604873) where the user is redirected to a new resource after he created one per `POST`. One reason for this pattern is to avoid a double `POST` if the user reloads a page.

Comment: I agree with you. I got deep in the weeds that I didnt think about it. I should think differently to solve my problem.