# Adjusting HTML based on PHP output / Response

Tags: php

I have read somewhere a long time ago that I could control how my php form and it's assets are dished up from the server by using somthing similar to the following;

`<?php if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {?> <div id="err"><?php echo $fnameErr, "<br/>", $lnameErr, "<br/>", $titleErr, "<br/>", $emailErr; ?></div> <?php } ?>`

More specifically I rememeber reading about page refreshing; in the sense that a page refresh will return a GET method rather than a post method. I'm not all that versed with php and I'm trying to understand the better practices for valdation and multiple form entry I.e. multiple submits. Is what I remember above true or is there a more practicle answer to my issue?

As highlighted by Pigeon the topic;

**POST / REDIRECT / GET**

I have since found a similar question on Stack that hover around the same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827242/understanding-post-redirect-get);

Comment: Are you talking about the [`Post/Redirect/Get`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern?

Comment: Yes after skim reading this appears to be based around the same article I read. This would be overkill for a simple web form though right? Surely there is a simpler way to accomplish multiple submits and or refresh...