# How does @Html.ListBox() and @Html.DropDownList() keep the state in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
            {
                //
                // GET: /Home/
                public ActionResult Index()
                {   
                    return View();
                }
                [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult Index(string list1)
                {
                    return View();
                }


            }
```

**View(uses default layout):**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.DropDownList("list1",
                        new SelectList(new[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" }))

    <input type="submit"/>
}
<br />
<br />
```

After selecting value in DropDownList and submitting the form my application have same state that was before. For example if i had selected "item 3" after pressing "submit" i have selected "item 3". How does it work?

**Upd:**

I dont want to avoid it, just want to understand how its work.

Comment: This is an issue(means you are not able to modify your dropdown selection item) or you are asking how this is happening?

Comment: No, i just want to know how working mechanism of state keeping, cause as we know "web is stateless". May be this "helpers" uses ModelState for it, i don`t know.

Comment: Please confirm whether the request is send to `server` on `submit`

Comment: Yes, and processed by `ActionResult Index(string list1)`

Comment: When you press button _Submit_, selected value of your select simply sends to `Index` method. Note that name of select and `string` parameter in `Index` method must be equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From MVC sources:**

***SelectExtensions.cs:***

```
.....
    object defaultValue = (allowMultiple) ? htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string[])) : htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string));
.....
```

***HtmlHelper.cs:***

```
internal object GetModelStateValue(string key, Type destinationType)
        {
            ModelState modelState;
            if (ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(key, out modelState))
            {
                if (modelState.Value != null)
                {
                    return modelState.Value.ConvertTo(destinationType, null /* culture */);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Well, it means that Action sends "ModelState" to view and controls(i know that it's not correct definition) use "ModelState" for fill themselves.

Answer (score 2):

In your `[Post]` handler you are not redirecting anywhere and returning a view directly. Hence the values persist because they are still found in the model state.

A common pattern is to [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10827242/11683) to a `[Get]` handler after a successful `Post`, in which case values would not persist.

Comment: @VladMelnik It also might be the browser restoring values in controls after page refresh. Set a breakpoint in the view and see if it has a value in its modelstate on the server side.

Comment: [Yes, it is(]http://image.prntscr.com/image/6b73430b8bf14614b403c9eb069d4502.png)

Comment: @VladMelnik Apparently the code you posted is not your actual code. On your screenshot the form is `method="get"`, so your `HttpPost` handler is never triggered, and the values persist because with `get` forms they are passed in the URL. In the code you posted, the form is `method="post"` (by default) so the `HttpPost` handler is triggered and the parameters are not passed in the URL.