# Error while browser go back button click

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

Im working with codeigniter framework, and i was doing a search page. when i enter keyword and search for that keyword, a list of result will show. From that list i click detail of one result, from that detail page i click browse back button it showing error page

> Confirm Form Resubmission
>
> This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed.
>   Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
>
> ERR_CACHE_MISS

this is my controller function

```
public function search(){
        $data["page"] = "search_companies";
        $base_url .= HOST_URL."/search/companies";
        $uri_array = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(3);
        if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) != 0) {
        $keyword = $this->input->post("search_txt", TRUE);
        $_SESSION['keyword']=$keyword;
        }
        else{
        $keyword=$_SESSION['keyword'];
        }
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
        $data['user_id']=$user_id;
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $offset    = (array_key_exists('offset',$uri_array) ? trim($uri_array["offset"]) : 0);
        $limit     = (!empty($paging) ? $paging : "30" );           
        $base_url .= "/offset";
        $limit1 =("6");
        $limit23 = ("6");           
        $total_records = $this->modelNameAlias->countSearchResults($keyword);
        $uri_segments  = $this->uri->total_segments();
        if($uri_segments==3){
        $uri_segments=4;
        }
        else{
        $uri_segments=$uri_segments;
        }       
        $config = user_side_paging($limit,$total_records, $base_url, $uri_segments);
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $by         = "DESC";
        $sortWith  = "added_date";
        $data_list = $this->modelNameAlias->get_search_records($keyword,$limit, $offset, $sortWith, $by);
        $this->load->model("model_followers");
        $where_array["user_id"] = $user_id;
        $where_array["is_active"] = "Y";    
        $data["data_user123"] = $this->model_followers->get_all_records($where_array, $limit23, $offset, $sortWith, $by);
        $where_array1["target_id"] = $user_id;
        $where_array1["is_active"] = "Y";
        $data["data_user_myf"] = $this->model_followers->get_all_records($where_array1, $limit1, $offset, $sortWith, $by );    
        $data["data_list"]        = $data_list;
        $data["search_text"]      = $keyword;
        $data["display_records"]  = display_records($total_records, $offset, $limit);
        $data["total_records"]    = $total_records;
        $data['offset']           = $offset;
        $data["paging"]           = $limit;
        $this->load->view("template", $data);
    }
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Show your search page code

Comment: You can't it is because you have sent data with post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827242/understanding-post-redirect-get

Comment: For search it better to use GET instead of POST, so user don't have type keywords again

Comment: Use GET method instead of POST. That will solve your issue

Comment: GET method works..thank you.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).