# Ajax Post request get converted to GET

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using ajax call to send google sign in information to my backend. But the POST ajax request status is showing as 302 and then it gets converted to GET. 
I found many solutions for this but nothing worked for me.

```js
function onSignIn(googleUser) {

  var profileObject = {}
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  var csrfmiddlewaretoken = 

  profileObject['name'] = profile.getName();
  profileObject['email'] = profile.getEmail();
  profileObject['csrftoken'] = getCookie('csrftoken');

  $.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: '/login/',
    data: JSON.stringify(profileObject),
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    success: function (response) {

    }
  });
};
```

I am using python django framework.

Comment: You have a typo: `type: "post"` should be `method: "post"`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing. Maybe I mistyped it while posting. 'method' is also giving the same result.

Comment: @FrankerZ is right and it should be `method: "POST"` in upper-case

Comment: @FrankerZ `type` was the original jQuery `$.ajax()` property and it still exists as an alias for `method` so that's definitely not the problem

Comment: This isn't a problem. What you're seeing is a typical [post / redirect / get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827242/understanding-post-redirect-get) flow. This is a very common pattern in handling HTTP POST requests

Comment: @qudrat POST is also not making any difference.

Comment: It is working fine when I am using the complete URL path i.e. "http://localhost:8000/en/accounts/login/". No Idea why it is behaving like this.

Comment: @JoshiR so looking at that, assuming your script is also running on `http://localhost:8000`, you want `url: '/en/accounts/login'`. When you prefix a URL path with a forward-slash, you're requesting a resource from the document root, so in your initial case, `/login/` resolves to `http://localhost:8000/login/`. See the difference?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the URL of the page running your JavaScript?

Comment: @Phil you are correct. it is getting resolved to http://localhost:8000/login/

Comment: It is running on http://localhost:8000/en/register/