# unable to passe page 2 by paginator on cakephp 2.9

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.9

I am currently facing a little problem. let me explain :
I develop a database under cakphp 2.9 I use a custom search function, the problem is that when I click on the next page I have an error that appears (the first page is displayed without worries)
this is my controller page : UsersController.php

```
public function search_club()
{
    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        $info1 = trim($this->request->data['Joueur']['CLUB']);
        //debug($info1); die();
        $joueurs = $this->Joueur->find('all', [
            'conditions' => [
                'AND' => [
                    'LOWER(Joueur.CLUB) LIKE' => '%' . strtolower($info1) . '%',
                    'Joueur.STATU' => '1'
                ]
            ]
        ]);

        //debug($joueurs); die();
        $this->Joueur->recursive = 0;
        $this->paginate = [
            'limit' => 20,
            'conditions' => [
                'and' => [
                    'Joueur.STATU' => '1',
                    'LOWER(Joueur.CLUB) LIKE' => '%' . strtolower($info1) . '%'
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $joueurs = $this->paginate('Joueur');
        $this->set('joueurs', $joueurs);
    }
}
```

this is my view file

```
<?php
 $paginator = $this->Paginator;

 foreach ($joueurs as $joueur):
    echo'<tbody>';
echo'<tr>';

        echo '<td class="hidden-480">
        <center>';
            echo $joueur['Joueur']['LICENCES'];
        echo'</center>
        </td> ';
        echo '<td class="hidden-480">
        <center>';
            echo $joueur['Joueur']['NOM'];
        echo'</center>
        </td> ';
        
        echo '<td class="hidden-480">
        <center>';
            echo $joueur['Joueur']['PRENOM'];
        echo'</center>
        </td> ';
        echo '<td class="hidden-480">
        <center>';
            echo $joueur['Joueur']['CLUB'];
        echo'</center>
        </td> ';
        echo'<td>
        <center>';
        echo $joueur['Joueur']['SEXE'];
        echo'</center>
        </td>';
        echo'<td>
        <center>';
        echo $joueur['Joueur']['NATIONALITE'];
        echo'</center>
        </td>';
        echo'<td>
        <center>';
        echo $joueur['Joueur']['PROVEN'];
        echo'</center>
        </td>';
         echo'<td>
        <center>
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-eye-o">&nbsp;</i>';
        echo $this->Html->link('Modifier/Voir',
            array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit_play', $joueur['Joueur']['id']),array('target' => '_blank'));
        echo'</center>
        </td>'; 
        echo '<td class="hidden-480">
        <center>';
         echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Supprimer'), array('action' => 'delet_play', $joueur['Joueur']['id']), null, __('Etes vous sûr de vouloir supprimé cet élément ?', $joueur['Joueur']['PRENOM']));  
        echo'</center>
        </td> 
    </tr>
    </tbody>';
    endforeach;
    unset($joueur);

        echo'</table>


    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
echo'
<div style="height:50px!important">

</div>';
 
// pagination section
    echo "<div class='paging' style='text-align:center'>";
 
        // the 'first' page button
        echo $paginator->first("Debut");
         
        // 'prev' page button, 
        // we can check using the paginator hasPrev() method if there's a previous page
        // save with the 'next' page button
        if($paginator->hasPrev()){
            echo $paginator->prev("Precedent");
        }
         
        // the 'number' page buttons
        echo $paginator->numbers(array('modulus' => 3));
         
        // for the 'next' button
        if($paginator->hasNext()){
            echo $paginator->next("Suivant");
        }
         
        // the 'last' page button
        echo $paginator->last("Fin");
     
    echo "</div>";("Fin");

  
     
  echo" </div>
    </div>";
 ?>
</div>
```

now this is this the error i got when a click on next page

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: joueurs [APP/View/Elements/resume_search_club.ctp, line 174]
>
> Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/View/Elements/resume_search_club.ctp, line 174]

I've been looking for a solution for several days, so please I really need your help on this one

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the complete controller method code, don't cut it off (possibly half way). Also try to format/indent it properly, that helps to spot flow control issues.

Comment: it is the complete controller methode code, i juste forget to add the end of these function, i will update that now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely at what your code is doing, when POST data is present, it will fetch data from the database in a paginated form, and set it as a view variable for use in your templates. Consequently it won't do any of that if no POST data is present, and that will of course be the case when you follow a (pagination) link, hence you'll receive those errors, as the data isn't being queried and the view variable isn't being set.

Long story short, use GET data (ie the query string) to pass the search term instead, either use GET data in the first place, ie change your form to use GET instead of POST, or use the [**PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) pattern**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827242/understanding-the-post-redirect-get-pattern) to transform your POST request to a GET request. Also you should have some sort of fail-safe so that things don't error out when the search term is missing, or the view variable isn't set.

Simple example with PRG:

```php
public function search_club()
{
    // Request with POST form data
    $term = $this->request->data('Joueur.CLUB');
    if ($term) {
        // Redirect as GET query string data
        return $this->redirect([
            '?' => [
                'term' => $term
            ]
        ]);
    }

    $conditions = [
        'Joueur.STATU' => '1',
    ];

    $term = $this->request->query('term');
    if ($term) {
        $conditions += [
            'LOWER(Joueur.CLUB) LIKE' => '%' . strtolower($term) . '%'
        ];
    }

    $this->paginate = [
        'limit' => 20,
        'conditions' => $conditions,
    ];

    $this->Joueur->recursive = 0;
    $joueurs = $this->paginate('Joueur');
    $this->set('joueurs', $joueurs);
}
```

Also make sure that the search term is being integrated in the URLs generated by the paginator helper, if it's not being included by default, you can [**modify the paginator options**](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#modifying-the-options-paginatorhelper-uses) and force it into the URL, like this:

```php
$this->Paginator->options([
    'url' => [
        '?' => [
            'term' => $this->request->query('term'),
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Comment: I just noticed that the search does not take place, all the elements appear as if there was no filter, however I confirm that the pagination works