# How to prevent auto-increment in database on page refresh? Laravel 7

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm having some condition(given below) to increment value by 1 in column('pass_number') of database table('quizzes'):

'quizzes':

```
Schema::create('quizzes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->string('qname');

        $table->text('description');

        $table->text('subcategory');

        $table->text('by');

        $table->text('by_username');

        $table->text('profileUrl');
        
        $table->integer('minutes');

        $table->integer('cutoff');
        
        $table->integer('pass_number')->default(0)->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

---

condition:

```
$cutoff1 = DB::table('quizzes')
                  ->where('id', '=', $quizId)
                  ->value('cutoff');

if ($percentage > $cutoff1) {

        DB::table('quizzes')
               ->where('id', $quizId)
               ->update([
                   'pass_number' => DB::raw('pass_number + 1')
               ]);
        
       }
```

I'm able to get increment in 'pass_number' but **on page refresh I want to stop it**.

*$percentage I'm getting from user's performance in particular quiz.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the "post/redirect/get" pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827242/understanding-the-post-redirect-get-pattern)

Comment: You have to do it by session value