# Can a Laravel POST route return a view instead of redirecting to another route?

Tags: laravel, post

I have seen/worked on lot of projects where a Laravel POST route looking like this:

```
Route::post('/some-url', [SomeController::class, 'someMethod']);
```

And the controller with its method which takes care of the route looking like this:

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function someMethod(Request $request) {
        // My Logic to do something with the post data - $request
        return redirect("/some-other-url");
    }
}
```

have always redirected to a specific URL after doing something with the POST data, by convention.

I would like to know, if after processing a POST request, if it's okay to just return a view like what we do with GET requests? I know it works, but is it just convention or are there any issues in doing so?

Eg:

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function someMethod(Request $request) {
        // My Logic to do something with the post data - $request
        return view("somebladeview")->with(["result" => $result ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, off course it is possible to return of view after hitting a POST request to the controller. This is mainly done when there is some sensitive information being submitted via the front end to the server using POST request and we need to process it and show a calculated response to the user in another view. There are no limitations for this. Please go ahead with returning a view instead of a redirect response if your project needs so. We've done it countless number of times. In fact most of the developers have done this, if I may say so.

Comment: Yes post requests can do this and if you look at any APIs implemented in Laravel they'll return JSON. It's simply considered best practise these days to perform a redirect from a post request if it's a user form submission etc.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, @Salvino and Peter Fox.

Comment: The pattern is called [post-redirect-get, or PRG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10827242).  It is convention because [POST should be used for requests that *change* data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46585), whereas GET should be used to simply display data.  If you return a view after a POST, the user can hit reload, and (probably unintentionally) change data again, eg buy something a second time.  By using PRG, the user hitting reload simply reloads the last GET, which just re-displays something.  I disagree with the advice above to go ahead and ignore this convention.

Comment: Thank you @Don'tPanic. I totally agree because, as you said, when I hit reload on the end screen (view that is displayed after POST), the browser asks to "confirm my resubmission", which is not the behavior I intend to keep. so your's should be the answer to my question, I guess. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern is called [post-redirect-get, or PRG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10827242). It is convention because [POST should be used for requests that change data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46585), whereas GET should be used to simply display data.

If you return a view after a POST, the user can hit reload, and (probably unintentionally) change data again, eg buy something a second time. By using PRG, the user hitting reload simply reloads the last GET, which just re-displays something.

**NOTE:** There is some advice in the comments on your question to ignore this convention.  I think that is unwise and dangerous, these conventions exist for good reasons.