# POST method opening new webpage

Tags: node.js, forms, api, rest, action

Below is the Form component of my webpage

```
 <form action="/login" method="POST">    
        <h3>Traditional Form</h3>
        <div class="form-row">
          <label for="name"> enter name </label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="false" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="block">submit</button>
</form>
```

And this is the api handling POST request

```
const express = require('express');
let app = express()
 
app.use(express.static("./methods-public"))       // storing html file
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))                 
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {  
  if (req.body.name)
    return res.status(200).send(`we go the person ${req.body.name}`)

  res.status(401).send("Wrong user")
})

app.listen(2600, () => console.log("We are listening"))
```

Now this is just the beginning , but what I am observing is that whenever I try to submit any data, I am led to the webpage `localhost:2600/login`. Now I realize that upon submitting the form , the data is sent to POST method for `/login` to handle , but it is a POST method. Why and how am I redirected to `localhost:2600/login` by an POST method ?

I want to know WHY & HOW it redirects use to new webpage. What happens at the backend in the logic that it redirects use to new webpageCan anyone please explain how any why is it happening so ?
Thank You

Comment: Is it happening with this form only? or any link you are trying to click on any webpage? your code seems fine and should not redirect. Also, try to check if somehow your `ctrl` button is not pressed, it happens often

Comment: It is happening with this form . And my ctrl button is not pressed.

Comment: try adding target='_self' if does help

Comment: This is just how typical HTML forms work. You click submit and are taken to the `action` URL. The method will either be `GET` or `POST`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the "post/redirect/get" pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827242/understanding-the-post-redirect-get-pattern). The answers outline the differences between a POST/REDIRECT/GET and a direct POST (what you're using) which should make things clearer for you

Comment: Not working , moreover I want to know the reason behind why it leads me to new webpage ?

Comment: @Phil , it is explaining what happens on sending these requests . I am more in understanding the  behind functioning of server. Like why and how it redirects to new page.Still it is a good thread .

Answer (score 0):

This is how HTML forms work. When you submit the form, the browser **navigates** to (opens) the `action` URL.

- If the `method` is `GET`, any form fields will be collected into the URL query string

  ```html
  <form action="https://example.com/" method="get">
  <input name="foo" value="FOO" />
  <button type="submit">Go</button>
  </form>
  ```

  ```
  GET https://example.com/?foo=FOO
  ```
- If the `method` is `POST`, any form fields are collected into the request body

  ```html
  <form action="https://example.com/" method="post">
  <input name="foo" value="FOO" />
  <button type="submit">Go</button>
  </form>
  ```

  ```
  POST https://example.com/
  content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

  foo=FOO
  ```

Either request will be sent to the server and the response rendered in the browser.

Note that the only valid methods for use in a form are `get` and `post` (well, and `dialog`).

For more information, see [Sending form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

Comment: So you want to say that whether the method is POST or GET  , one thing is for sure that is the website will be led to the URL page given in action tag , is it so ?

Comment: That is correct. A common pattern is _post / redirect / get_ as illustrated in the post I linked earlier which avoids some of the issues with straight post requests