# Thymeleaf th:replace by application POST request

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using fragment replace for my menu bar view, I need the view loaded from Controller with Spring Modal attributes. However th:replace seems to be works only for template resolving instead of a POST method request. I had a POST request ***http://localhost:8080/myapp/menu*** responding view with menu populated.

Basically I looking for a way to load a Thymeleaf fragment which is a POST response view.

Using: Spring 6, Thymeleaf 3

Below are my snapshot of code.

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <!-- @{} to have server relative path append -->
    <div th:replace="@{~/menu}"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

menu.html

```
<div xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <script th:inline="javascript">
        $(document).ready(() => {
            var menuList = /*[[${menuList}]]*/ null;
            console.log(menuList);
            if(null != menuList){
                // some logic to populate menu
            }
        })
    </script>
    
    <div id="menu">...</div>
</div>
```

MenuController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/menu", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String menu(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, Model model) {
        logger.debug("menu controller");
        List<Menu> menuList = null;
        Object object = httpServletRequest.getServletContext().getAttribute(SESSION_NAME_MENU);

        if(Objects.nonNull(object)){
            try{
                menuList = (List<Menu>) object;
            } catch (Exception e){}
        }

        if(Objects.isNull(menuList)){
            Menu home = new Menu();
            home.setId(1L);
            home.setTitle("Home");
            home.setUrl("home.html");
            menuList.add(home);

            // ...
        }

        model.addAttribute("menuList", menuList);
        return "layout/menu";
    }
```

I understand that there is workaround in menu.html javascript part which calling ajax with json response for menu object, however having a POST response view loaded into a main view is very common scenario.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. For one you don't even explain what is going wrong. What Thymeleaf does (including `th:replace`) has normally nothing to do with the HTTP method that was used. Why are you using POST here anyway? POST is for sending data to the server, which doesn't seem to happen here. Also responding to a POST request with an HTML page is generally considered an anti-pattern. Check out the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern}(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827242/understanding-the-post-redirect-get-pattern).