# How can I stop submitting a form on page refresh in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Consider that I have a form like this:

```
<form method="get" action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?> style='margin:auto;text-align:center' id="send" >
<input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="<?php echo $questionid ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="answered" value='true'>
<input id='submitbtn' type="button" <?php if($answered=='true')echo "style='display:none'";?> onclick="send()" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Actually, I am creating an exam-based website. What I am trying to do is, if the user clicks the submit button, the function `send()` is triggered and the form is submitted:

```
function send(){    
document.getElementById('send').submit();
<?php 
$answered="true";
if(isset($_COOKIE["upstr"]))
$updata=$_COOKIE["upstr"];
else $updata="";
$upsql="UPDATE question_data SET answered='$answered', ansstr='$updata', timespnt='$timetaken' WHERE questionid='$questionid'";
$conn->execute_query($upsql);
?>
    document.cookie="upstr=''; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;"
}
```

Here `upstr` is a simple cookie that stores the values that the user has clicked to validate later. Here the php variable `$answered` turns `true` from `false` as the form is submitted.

What I am facing as the problem is, the user, if for any reason, reloads the page, the form is submitted. I was also storing the time the user required to solve the question and stores it as the `php` variable `$timespnt` but it does not work too. I think my problem is that the form gets submitted on pressing the refresh page button. Any idea on how to solve it? Or am I facing something different?

Edit: This is what have tried finally...

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    
var Timer;
var TotalSeconds;
<?php
$time=6;
$length=1;
$timetaken=6*$length-$time;
$questionid=7;
$answered="false";
$servername = "****";
$dbusername = "****";
$dbpassword = "****";
$dbname= "****";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
?>
function CreateTimer(TimerID, Time) {
    Timer = document.getElementById(TimerID);
    TotalSeconds = Time;
    UpdateTimer();
    console.log(TotalSeconds);
    window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);}

function Tick() {
    TotalSeconds -= 1;
    if(TotalSeconds==0){
        <?php $answered="true";?>
        document.cookie="timer="+TotalSeconds+"expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;";
    }

    else{
    UpdateTimer()
    window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
}
}

function UpdateTimer() {
Timer.innerHTML = TotalSeconds;
document.cookie="timer="+TotalSeconds;}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $answered;?>
<!--Outputs "true" here but why?-->
<div id='timer'></div>

<?php 
if (isset($_REQUEST["submitButton"]) || isset($_REQUEST["submitted"])){
  $answered="true";
  $updata=$_REQUEST["updata"];
  $upsql="UPDATE question_data SET answered='$answered', ansstr='$updata', timespnt='$timetaken' WHERE questionid='$questionid'";
  $conn->execute_query($upsql);  
}
?>

<form method="REQUEST" action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?> style='margin:auto;text-align:center' id="send" >
<input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="<?php echo $questionid ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="timeout" />
<input type="hidden" name="updata" value="" />
<?php if($answered !='true') 
echo"<input name=\"submitButton\" type=\"submit\" value=\"SUBMIT\">";
?>
</form>


</body>
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let tId;
  const form = document.getElementById('send')
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    clearTimeout(tId);
    form.querySelector('[name=submitted]').value = 'formsubmit'; // user pressed SUBMIT
    form.querySelector('[name=updata]').value =userchoice.toString();
});
  tId = setTimeout(() => form.submit(),30*60*1000); // submit in 30 minutes
});

var userchoice=['a','b','c'];
//userchoice be the answers that the user has choosen

<?php
if($answered=='false')
echo 'window.onload = CreateTimer("timer",'. $time.');';
else echo 'document.write("Submission Completed");';
?>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But I have something more to know. Is there any way to check if my cookies for storing the time spent are okay? Second, why does the value of `php` variable `$answered` is set to `"true"` though it is supposed to be `"false"` at the first comment after the `body` tag?

Comment: `function send(){    
document.getElementById('send').submit();`...this is completely unnecessary. Just make a `<button type="submit"` in the HTML and it will submit by default, without needing a script

Comment: `if for any reason, reloads the page`...what reason would they have? Normally the browser will warn them if they are re-submitting the form, but this warning can be disabled - and I'm not 100% if it will take place or not since your form uses a GET instead of POST (it's unclear why it does that). But ultimately if the user decided to submit the data twice, that is their error, not yours. If it's a big issue you _can_ work round it with the post->redirect->get pattern though - read more here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827242/understanding-the-post-redirect-get-pattern

Comment: Also if you need to do stuff, do it using the form's submit event - herre the `send`  is the ID of the form: `document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); /* if you do NOT want to submit */ stuffToDo()});`

Comment: @ADyson I need that `document.getElementById('send').submit()` in my code, since after 30 minutes I want the form to be auto submitted by using this 'send()' function.

Comment: Your submit is triggered by `onclick="send()"` though, not by automation. That isn't needed. I see no evidence of any automation in your code. Even if you did, you could just trigger `document.getElementById('send').submit()` via a `setTimeout` call. You don't need the `send()` or the `onclick` for that, and you don't need them for a user-triggered submit either if you have a proper submit button

Comment: Then do that in a setTimeout and not on the button. And leave the script out if already submitted

Comment: @ADyson I just noticed that the browser does not warn the user to resubmit the form, since they are not filling any form really. They are just clicking some divs in my page, that they consider to be the answer of the questions.

Comment: `since they are not filling any form really`....no, `document.getElementById('send').submit()` definitely submits a form. So the browser will consider a form to have been submitted when that gets executed. Therefore it might issue a warning if you try to refresh immediately after that - although as I said, that may only happen after a submit via POST, not GET...perhaps you can test that (I'm not in a position to do so right now)

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, POST method arises a warning. But I need to have the url parameter passed to the url, so I need to have the GET method here.

Comment: @mplungjan How do I change my button in this form? Any help on that?

Comment: `I need to have the url parameter passed to the url`...why? You could surely adjust the PHP code to accept POST data instead

Comment: `How do I change my button in this form`...I think my very first comment explained that. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#type . Unless you want to make some other kind of change? If so you haven't explained

Comment: @ADyson Because I am using a parameter `questionid` in my url that generates question for each of the id and stores it in a database. I need to have this `questionid` and its value in the url to work.

Comment: `I need to have this questionid and its value in the url to work`.... you can still do that, even if you POST the rest of the data. Or, your form already has questionID as a hidden field, so it would just be sent via POST instead, and your PHP code can still use it. Since you're posting data in that instance, it doesn't really have any negative impact to remove it (unless your code has a very strange design). URL parameters are more useful when _getting_ data, generally

Comment: Any article on that? `POST the rest of the data`? Is it possible to just show the `questionid` parameter on the url on the GET method and set the other parameter `answered`  passed on the POST method. I think not.

Comment: Of course it is. The `action` of the form would contain the URL that the request goes to, including any parameters to be included in that URL. The form fields are then posted when the `method=POST`. Completely normal and common thing to do.

Comment: @ADyson I have changed a few things here. I have removed the hidden fields and changed the last input of `type="button"` to `<button type="submit">` and still there is no change here. The user refreshes the page and then the form gets submitted and my database is being filled. But I have kept the `send()` function since I need the cookie. But removed 'submit()' here. What's next?

Comment: What is the cookie for? PHP could always set a cookie though, if you really need to. What's next either way is to start using POST to submit the data. You really also ought to parameterise your query properly too, to prevent the risk of SQL injection and other related problems.

Comment: `why does the value of php variable $answered is set to "true"`...because earlier on in the code you wrote `<?php $answered="true";?>`, which is always executed when your page loads.

Comment: `Is there any way to check if my cookies for storing the time spent are okay` ...well you can use your browser's Developer Tools to check what cookies are currently present in your page, and what they look like.

Comment: 1. No need to use cookies at all. You are submitting the form so store the values in the form. If you want the user to stop and continue later, you can use localStorage instead of cookies2. Use method="POST" on the form and if the action has ?questionid=... then on the servere you can use $_REQUEST to read both POST and GET variables. If you  use a hidden field on the form to store questionID then you do NOT need REQUEST anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at this version which uses POST and gets rid of the cookies

The code is not tested and I assume the answers are mad by adding the class "answer" to a clicked div

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let tId; // placeholder
  const form = document.getElementById('send')
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    clearTimeout(tId); // stop the timeout
    form.querySelector('[name=submitted]').value = 'formsubmit'; // user pressed SUBMIT
    form.querySelector('[name=updata]').value = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.answer')).map(answer => answer.textContent.trim()); // all divs with class = answer.
  });
  tId = setTimeout(() => form.submit(),30*60*1000); // submit in 30 minutes
});
```

```html
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["submitButton"]) || isset($_POST["submitted"]))
  $answered="true";
  $updata = $_POST["updata"]) 
  $upsql="UPDATE question_data SET answered='$answered', ansstr='$updata', timespnt='$timetaken' WHERE questionid='$questionid'";
  $conn->execute_query($upsql);
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" style="margin:auto;text-align:center" id="send" >
<input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="<?php echo $questionid ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="timeout" />
<input type="hidden" name="updata" value="" />
<?php if($answered !='true') {
<input name="submitButton" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `<form method="post" action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'?questionid='.$questionid;?> style='margin:auto;text-align:center' id="send" >`?`

Comment: I do not recommend it but you can. Just change the $_POST/$_GET to $_REQUEST to get them both

Comment: Would you kindly check my edit on the question? I would be grateful to you. Thank you.

Comment: Can you help me understand the part `if (isset($_POST["submitButton"]) || isset($_POST["submitted"]))`? What does it actually do? When does the condition runs? And when does it not?

Comment: It interrogates two values that are passed by the form being submitted. EITHER the submit button was pressed OR the field value submitted is set by the script. In both cases we want the script to run. [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: `Can you help me understand the part...` here there is something to remind you, which is that, while the page loads for the first time [there has been no reload before], the variable `submitButton` remains unset, so the form is not submitted as the if statement is not executed. [even if you reload the page] Second, once you submit the form, then if you change the database and reload the page, the variable `answered` is set to false but the variable `submitButton` remains set, so the if-block then continues to work even when you reload the page [though it did not happen the first time].